# editing drop down values on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i'm currently working with ajax and i'm having problems with drop downs,
i have this function that gets data from the database and outputs it on textfields and a dropdown form, i have no problem getting the data and outputting it on the text fields and dropdown but when I update the value of the text field it doesn't do so. the variable that is in the drop down is the user_type

```
$(function users() {
    $("a.edit-users").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#editUser').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        $.ajax({
            url:'users/retrieve',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'userid': $(this).data('userid')
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, status) {
                $('#uuserid').val(data.userid);
                $('#uusername').val(data.username);
                $('#upassword').val(data.password);
                $('#ufullname').val(data.fullname);       
                $('#uemail_add').val(data.email_add); 
                $('#uuser_type').val(data.user_type);
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is where I edit the data

```
<div id="editUser" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<?php echo form_open('users/update');?>
  <form>
  <h3 align="center">Edit User</h3>
                  <div class="row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="uuserid" />
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                      <label>Full Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="fullname" id="ufullname" placeholder="max 16 char" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                      <label for="user_type">User Type</label>
                      <select for="user_type">
                        <option value="admin" name="user_type" id="uuser_type">Administrator</option>
                        <option value="head_mgr" name="user_type" id="uuser_type">Head Manager</option>
                        <option value="branch_mgr" name="user_type" id="uuser_type">Branch Manager</option>
                        <option value="employee" name="user_type" id="uuser_type">Employee</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                   </div>

                 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update"  class="small radius button" style="margin-left: 440px;">
  </form>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML markup.

Comment: your markup is wrong.. give name and id to `select` not to options

Comment: changed it and it worked, was focused on the ajax that i didn't notice the markup was wrong, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your drop-down id

```
<select for="user_type" id="uuser_type">
       <option value="admin" name="user_type">Administrator</option>
       <option value="head_mgr" name="user_type">Head Manager</option>
       <option value="branch_mgr" name="user_type">Branch Manager</option>
       <option value="employee" name="user_type">Employee</option>
</select>
```